# How do you update VUE elements when running a promise

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js

I have a login screen and want to display a loading element when submitted and stop it when any errors occur.

I am not sure how to update the DOM when the promise has resolved.

Using Vue.js, Vuex, and Vuetify.

The only thing I can see is set a variable on the actual state in vuex but this won't work if multiple load elements use that and you change the state all loading elements will become visible.

I have tried numerous things and also googled. But we worked from a boilerplate and can't really find examples that matches our use case.

Here is my front end code.

```
<template>
  <div class="auth-page">
    <div class="container page">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3 col-xs-12">
          <h1 class="text-xs-center">Login</h1>
          <p class="text-xs-center"></p>
          <ul v-if="errors" class="error-messages">
            <!-- <li v-for="(v, k) in errors" :key="k">{{ k }} {{ v | error.title }}</li> -->
            <li v-for="(v, k) in errors" :key="k">{{ v.detail }}</li>
          </ul>
          <form v-on:submit.prevent="onSubmit(email, password);">
            <fieldset class="form-group">
              <input
                class="form-control form-control-lg"
                type="text"
                v-model="email"
                placeholder="Email"
              />
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="form-group">
              <input
                class="form-control form-control-lg"
                type="password"
                v-model="password"
                placeholder="Password"
              />
            </fieldset>
            <v-progress-circular
              right
              :size="30"
              color="black"
              indeterminate
              v-show="isLoading"
            ></v-progress-circular>
            <button
              class="btn btn-lg btn-primary pull-xs-right"
              style="background:black; border-color:black"
            >
              Login
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from "vuex";
import { LOGIN } from "@/store/actions.type";

export default {
  name: "RwvLogin",
  data() {
    return {
      email: null,
      password: null,
      isLoading: false
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onSubmit(email, password) {
      this.isLoading = true;
      this.$store
        .dispatch(LOGIN, { email, password })
        // .then(() => this.$router.push({ name: "policies" }));
        .then(() => this.$router.push({ name: "policies" }))
        .catch((e) => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      errors: state => state.auth.errors
    })
  }
};
</script>
```

and the module code:

```
import ApiService from "@/common/api.service";
import JwtService from "@/common/jwt.service";
import {
  LOGIN,
  LOGOUT,
  REGISTER,
  CHECK_AUTH,
  UPDATE_USER
} from "./actions.type";
import { SET_AUTH, PURGE_AUTH, SET_ERROR } from "./mutations.type";

const state = {
  errors: null,
  user: {},
  isLoading: false,
  isAuthenticated: !!JwtService.getToken()
};

const getters = {
  currentUser(state) {
    return state.user;
  },
  isAuthenticated(state) {
    return state.isAuthenticated;
  },
  isLoading(state) {
    return state.isLoading;
  }
};

const actions = {
  [LOGIN](context, credentials) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      ApiService.post("login", credentials)
        .then(({ data }) => {
          context.commit(SET_AUTH, data.access_token);
          resolve(data);
        })
        .catch(({ response }) => {
          if(response.status == 401){
            response.data.errors = [{"status":"401","code":0,"title":"Loginn error","detail":"The password entered is incorrect."}] 
          }
          context.commit(SET_ERROR, response.data.errors);
        });
    });
  },
  [LOGOUT](context) {
    context.commit(PURGE_AUTH);
  },
  [REGISTER](context, credentials) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      ApiService.post("users", credentials)
        .then(({ data }) => {
          context.commit(SET_AUTH, data.access_token);
          resolve(data);
        })
        .catch(({ response }) => {
          context.commit(SET_ERROR, response.data.errors);
          reject(response);
        });
    });
  },
  [CHECK_AUTH](context) {
    if (JwtService.getToken()) {
      // ApiService.setHeader();
      // ApiService.get("user")
      //   .then(({ data }) => {
      //     context.commit(SET_AUTH, data.access_token);
      //   })
      //   .catch(({ response }) => {
      //     context.commit(SET_ERROR, response.data.errors);
      //   });
    } else {
      context.commit(PURGE_AUTH);
    }
  },
  [UPDATE_USER](context, payload) {
    const { email, username, password, image, bio } = payload;
    const user = {
      email,
      username,
      bio,
      image
    };
    if (password) {
      user.password = password;
    }

    return ApiService.put("user", user).then(({ data }) => {
      context.commit(SET_AUTH, data.user);
      return data;
    });
  }
};

const mutations = {
  [SET_ERROR](state, error) {
    state.errors = error;
  },
  [SET_LOADING](state, loading_state) {
    state.isLoading = loading_state;
  },
  [SET_AUTH](state, token) {
    state.isAuthenticated = true;
    state.errors = {};
    state.token = token;
    JwtService.saveToken(state.token);
  },
  [PURGE_AUTH](state) {
    state.isAuthenticated = false;
    state.user = {};
    state.policies = {};
    state.errors = {};
    JwtService.destroyToken();
  }
};

export default {
  state,
  actions,
  mutations,
  getters
};
```

So when clicking submit it runs the LOGIN function which talks to our API. this will return either a wrong password or validation errors. The errors are displaying perfectly.

On submit I do `this.isLoading = true;` and when it returns the error it must `this.isLoading = false;`

Not sure where to do that.

Any help helping me understand this will be great.

Answer (score 0):

you want a loading in this page, not in all pages, so you'd better  manage `isLoading` locally, no need to put it in the vuex store.

For example, you can add `finally` to the Promise in your `onSubmit` method, you can cancel the loading state in that:

```
onSubmit(email, password) {
  this.isLoading = true;
  this.$store
    .dispatch(LOGIN, { email, password })
    // .then(() => this.$router.push({ name: "policies" }));
    .then(() => this.$router.push({ name: "policies" }))
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log(e);
    }).finally(() => this.isLoading = false);
}
```

By the way, `vuex` is used for `global state` management, you don't have to put all the state in it. you should know locale state and global state, otherwise you will get lost in the big, global state map.

For the global state, I think less is better

Comment: Thanks, Johnson Lee. Tried the above but it didn't work. The catch and finally doesn't actually action. I know the difference between local and global but getting kinda fed up with not getting this working.

I added the finally method but that doesn't action.

Comment: @JanesOosthuizen it might be because of your `$router.push` which causes the page to refresh. Basically, you execute the dispatch and lose the track of your Promise by refreshing, so you can't reach the `.finally` method. In this case you should declare a temp variable `let doPush = false` at the beginning of your `onSubmit()` method, then just change it to `true` in your `then()` statement.
The point of doing this is to execute the `$router.push` inside the finally statement, only if you have `doPush` set to true.

Comment: @RyoShiina What you say makes sense but if it errors the redirect doesn't happen. Even after removing the redirect the finally step still doesn't happen which is leading me to think that something is stopping the whole process from going any further than the "then" step.

Comment: @JanesOosthuizen That's weird I agree, let's just try the little fixes we can bring: write a `reject(response)` in your `LOGIN` Promise. That might solve the issue that nothing is happening in case of an error. You'll need to add `reject` as a parameter as well.

Answer (score 0):

So how I ended up doing this by using a global state variable to show and hide the progress and updating that variable whenever I action items in the background see code below.

With this method, I can have multiple progress bars on the page and updating specific ones by modifying the code slightly.

Please anyone who knows vue.js well please give opinion or guidance.

```
<template>
  <div class="auth-page">
    <div class="container page">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3 col-xs-12">
          <h1 class="text-xs-center">Login</h1>
          <p class="text-xs-center"></p>
          <ul v-if="errors" class="error-messages">
            <!-- <li v-for="(v, k) in errors" :key="k">{{ k }} {{ v | error.title }}</li> -->
            <li v-for="(v, k) in errors" :key="k">{{ v.detail }}</li>
          </ul>
          <form v-on:submit.prevent="onSubmit(email, password);">
            <fieldset class="form-group">
              <input
                class="form-control form-control-lg"
                type="text"
                v-model="email"
                placeholder="Email"
              />
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="form-group">
              <input
                class="form-control form-control-lg"
                type="password"
                v-model="password"
                placeholder="Password"
              />
            </fieldset>
            <v-progress-circular
              right
              :size="30"
              color="black"
              indeterminate
              v-show="this.$store.getters.isLoading"
            ></v-progress-circular>
            <button
              class="btn btn-lg btn-primary pull-xs-right"
              style="background:black; border-color:black"
            >
              Login
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";
import { mapState } from "vuex";
import { LOGIN } from "@/store/actions.type";

export default {
  name: "RwvLogin",
  data() {
    return {
      email: null,
      password: null
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onSubmit(email, password) {
      this.$store.commit(SET_LOADING, true);
      this.$store
        .dispatch(LOGIN, { email, password })
        .then(() => this.$router.push({ name: "policies" }));
    }
  },
  mounted() {

  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      errors: state => state.auth.errors
    })
  }
};
</script>
```

```
import ApiService from "@/common/api.service";
import JwtService from "@/common/jwt.service";
import {
  LOGIN,
  LOGOUT,
  REGISTER,
  CHECK_AUTH,
  UPDATE_USER
} from "./actions.type";
import { SET_AUTH, PURGE_AUTH, SET_ERROR, SET_LOADING } from "./mutations.type";

const state = {
  errors: null,
  user: {},
  isLoading: false,
  isAuthenticated: !!JwtService.getToken()
};

const getters = {
  currentUser(state) {
    return state.user;
  },
  isLoading(state) {
    return state.isLoading;
  },
  isAuthenticated(state) {
    return state.isAuthenticated;
  }
};

const actions = {
  [LOGIN](context, credentials) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      ApiService.post("login", credentials)
        .then(({ data }) => {
          context.commit(SET_AUTH, data.access_token);
          resolve(data);
        })
        .catch(({ response }) => {
          context.commit(SET_LOADING, false);
          if(response.status == 401){
            response.data.errors = [{"status":"401","code":0,"title":"Loginn error","detail":"The password entered is incorrect."}] 
          }
          context.commit(SET_ERROR, response.data.errors);
        });
    });
  },
  [LOGOUT](context) {
    context.commit(PURGE_AUTH);
  },
  [REGISTER](context, credentials) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      ApiService.post("users", credentials)
        .then(({ data }) => {
          context.commit(SET_AUTH, data.access_token);
          resolve(data);
        })
        .catch(({ response }) => {
          context.commit(SET_ERROR, response.data.errors);
          reject(response);
        });
    });
  },
  [CHECK_AUTH](context) {
    if (JwtService.getToken()) {
      // ApiService.setHeader();
      // ApiService.get("user")
      //   .then(({ data }) => {
      //     context.commit(SET_AUTH, data.access_token);
      //   })
      //   .catch(({ response }) => {
      //     context.commit(SET_ERROR, response.data.errors);
      //   });
    } else {
      context.commit(PURGE_AUTH);
    }
  },
  [UPDATE_USER](context, payload) {
    const { email, username, password, image, bio } = payload;
    const user = {
      email,
      username,
      bio,
      image
    };
    if (password) {
      user.password = password;
    }

    return ApiService.put("user", user).then(({ data }) => {
      context.commit(SET_AUTH, data.user);
      return data;
    });
  }
};

const mutations = {
  [SET_ERROR](state, error) {
    state.errors = error;
  },
  [SET_LOADING](state, status) {
    state.isLoading = status;
  },
  [SET_AUTH](state, token) {
    state.isAuthenticated = true;
    state.errors = {};
    state.token = token;
    JwtService.saveToken(state.token);
  },
  [PURGE_AUTH](state) {
    state.isAuthenticated = false;
    state.user = {};
    state.policies = {};
    state.errors = {};
    JwtService.destroyToken();
  }
};

export default {
  state,
  actions,
  mutations,
  getters
};
```